# Duplicate global variable

Tags: c, global-variables

I need to use a global variable in multiple translation units, so I put

```c
int g_exit_status;
```

in a header file and included that header in my source files. The default value for global variables is zero, but I need to use a specific value. I tried to specifying a value (e.g. 90), but then I received this error while compiling:

```
duplicate symbol '_g_exit_status' in:
    /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000kch0004l4/T/main-422e60.o
    /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000kch0004l4/T/parsing-328bc4.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [minishell] Error 1
```

Comment: Put `extern int g_exit_status;` in the header file, and put `int g_exit_status = 90;` in one of the .c files.

Comment: *Define* global variables in a single source file. *Declare* the variable in the header file (as in `extern int g_exit_status;`)

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
int g_exit_status;
```

is a [tentative definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern), which will act as a **definition** unless that variable is defined somewhere else in the same translation unit (i.e. in the same `.c` file). In the latter case, it will instead act as a **declaration**.

The line

```
int g_exit_status = 90;
```

is a **definition**.

The line

```
extern int g_exit_status;
```

is a **declaration**.

A definition is also a declaration, but not vice-versa.

You must **declare** the variable `g_exit_status` in all translation units in which it is used. However, according to the [one-definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern#One_definition_rule), you must **define** it in exactly one translation unit. You appear to be violating this rule by putting a definition inside a header file that is included by multiple translation units.

For the reasons stated above, the declaration

```
extern int g_exit_status;
```

should be inside the header file, but the definition

```
int g_exit_status = 90;
```

should only be inside a single `.c` file, in order to not violate the one-definition rule.

Comment: int g_exit_status; is a definition and i put it  in the header file violating one-definition rule what didnt that cause an error?

Comment: @Mohammad: It did cause an error. Because you included the definition `int g_exit_status;` in multiple translation units (`.c` files), the linker symbol `_g_exit_status` was defined twice, which caused the linker to emit the error message that you posted in the question. You are probably confused because the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) did not complain, it was the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) that complained. That is why the error message looks different than a compiler error message.

Comment: im afraid you didnt read my question well, i said why it didnt cause an error

Comment: @Mohammad: According to the information that I specified in my answer, using `int g_exit_status;` should also give you a linker error. If that is not the case, then my only explanation is that you are using an old version of clang (clang 10 or lower) or you are compiling with the `-fcommon` command-line option. Note that before clang 11, clang defaulted to using `-fcommon`. Since clang 11, it defaults to using `-fno-common`. See the [release notes for clang 11](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) for further information.

Comment: @Mohammad: Which version of clang are you using? Does it stop working if you compile with `-fno-common`?

Comment: @Mohammad: See [this gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) for a description of what `-fcommon` does.